# softlayer api MassAccessControlModification error while updating block storage

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
SoftLayer_Exception_Network_Storage_Group_MassAccessControlModification: Errors occurred while modifying access for the requested SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest objects:
SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest #29063977: An error occurred while manipulating access control for this volume.  If this error persists, please contact Support.
(HTTP 500)
```

I get this exception intermittently while updating the authorized host list of a block storage. Possibly due to repeated calls to http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHost. To counter I tried checking active transactions from http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getActiveTransactions hoping that while a host is being added to block storage the `activeTransactions` will populate but I'm still facing intermittent issue of `MassAccessControlModification`.

Is the error due to repeated `allowAccessFromHost` calls?
If yes, how can I counter it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error happens when you try to add twice the same host at same time, the  http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHost. method does not generate any transaction, so will not help you to verify if the transaction has been accomplished.

You could try to verify if your machines has been added successfully using any of these methods:

http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowedVirtualGuests
http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowedIpAddresses
http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/getAllowedHardware

The methods return the machines with allow access to the storage.

Once you call the method SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHost try calling any of the methods above to verify if your machines has been added successfully once you see them listed make your next call avoiding adding machines that al;ready has been added.

Regards

Comment: I was able to recreate this error by trying to add a virtual guest to the **same** block storage twice at the same time. Would you be knowing if the error can happen if a virtual guest is added to two **different** block storages at the same time?

Comment: Yep it is reproduccible I recommend to use SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::allowAccessToNetworkStorageList method to attach a VSI at several storages at same time

Comment: I tried two changes. Replaced `SoftLayer_Network_Storage::AllowAccessFromHostList` with `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::allowAccessToNetworkStorageList ` for virtual guests and replaced with `SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress::AllowAccessToNetworkStorageList` for IP address. For adding virtual guests, the problem **seems** to go away. But for IP address, I still get the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: what IP address issue?

Comment: The issue I'm facing is not just for adding a virtual guest to block storages. e.g. I can add IP address to block storages as well as given here http://developer.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/allowAccessFromHost

In link, there is parameter `typeClassName` which can be `virtual guest` or `ip address`.

`MassAccessControlModification` occurs when 1)virtual guest is added to two block storages at same exact time or 2) IP address is added to two block storages at the same exact time

Comment: So while using `SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::allowAccessToNetworkStorageList` seems to have resolved it for point 1. Using its equivalent `SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress::AllowAccessToNetworkStor‌​ageList` did not resolve for point 2

Comment: ufff tough bro, let me check

Comment: SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress::AllowAccessToNetworkStor‌​‌​ageList for that method it seems issue with the API I will report it to softlayer, if this is blocking you I recomend you to open a ticket and tell them that this is an issue in order they can fix it more quickly or give you another solution

Comment: Well I simply added logic to catch the exception and retry. So I'm not blocked. But thanks for all the help. By ticket do you mean the ticket section in the softlayer portal? I've never reported an issue but if you plan to report I'd love to see it just for information.